Monitor signal cutting in and out repeatedly after hibernation
I am on Windows 11. This started happening only a few days ago after I had manually ended the LampArray Translation Service from Task Manager. Many users are suggesting this task interferes with Logitech's software that controls RGB on their products and to end the task. However, ending this task just that once has caused nothing but this mysterious problem.
Notably, restarting my computer temporarily fixes the problem until the next hibernation.
Does anybody know what is happening? Can anybody help me troubleshoot this?
I believe it had something to do with Logitech's G HUB software as I took a look at Windows Events and then uninstalled the software. No issues after testing or deliberately trying to instigate the issue the issue so far.
